# How your app[s] is going?

Tags: discussion

Do you mind to share your current experience with your live app[s]?

- Are you still working/updating it?
- Are you getting traffic/popularity?
- Got some good review/link from some big fish?
- In which way are you promoting it?
- Are you going to monetize it in some way?

<sup>Sorry but CW is gone and probably this question would have fit well</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the functionality I aimed to provide has been included in SE proper since then, so most of it I've just let it sit and decay (global search and moderator analytics are the two big ones).

That said, the one app that I've not actively developed ([Column 80](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu)), because of its incredible simplicity) but still check every now and again is still getting traffic. Traffic heavilly spiked in June 2010 (due to the contest, fresh entry, etc) but still gets regular monthly traffic of around 100-150 users a month which is about what I would expect for such a niche app.

Answer (score 1):

Not promoting StackTop, not updating StackTop, still get some traffic.

StackTop was more of a learning experience for me then an app that I could sell.

Also, I don't understand why they would remove CW.  It was an extremely useful feature!

Comment: You have probably noticed it, but CW has only been removed from questions - see [Should the community wiki police be shut down?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392) and  [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/67039) for the background. I've been in favor of optional CW for questions myself, and given this u-turn only a couple of month later, the premature harsh [policing and resulting moderation](http://stackapps.com/questions/1426) regarding CW questions here at Stack Apps seem to be even less justified, alas ...

Answer (score 1):

- **Are you still working/updating it?**

  Yes, I'm still keeping my applications as up to date as I can with the time I have. Obviously this is not as often as I'd like, but I do the best I can. Even after the contest, I still added 2 or 3 new apps to StackApps.
- **Are you getting traffic/popularity?**

  The ones that were doing well before are still doing fairly well. Of particular interest is [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s), which has been swamped with traffic from feed aggregators and browsers.
- **Got some good review/link from some big fish?**

  By that I take it you mean "have the apps been mentioned on any large sites/publications?" The answer for me is yes. [StackMobile](https://stackapps.com/questions/36/stackmobile-com-view-stackexchange-sites-on-your-smartphone) was featured on [wapreview.com](http://wapreview.com/?nonMobile=1&id=2952) and [stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php-stack-php-0-3-released) was featured in a [Zend Developer article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/12829-Using-the-Stack-Exchange-API-with-PHP-part-1). [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop-v1-4-released) was actually included in the [official Ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/stackapplet).
- **In which way are you promoting it?**

  I'm promoting my apps on Meta when they solve a problem or feature-request. I was also advertising some of the open source apps/libraries through [StackOverflow's own ad network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011).
- **Are you going to monetize it in some way?**

  No. I do not have any intention of making money off of my apps. (Too complicated and probably not viable.)

Comment: Stack2RSS is getting more traffic than StackMobile?

Comment: @sys: I really don't know which is getting more traffic.

Answer (score 0):

- **Are you still working/updating it?**

  Yep, I really like adding [useless features](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/changelog.txt) just to waste time.
- **Are you getting traffic/popularity?**

  The traffic is raised to 1K visits/day three weeks ago when Google started indexing [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) pretty well.
- **Got some good review/link from some big fish?**

  Not really with one exception, [linux-magazine.com](http://www.linux-magazine.com/) .
- **In which way are you promoting it?**

  I'm promoting my app on Meta when it solves some printer-friendly issues.
  I don't think my apps properly fit in [opensource advertising](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/74983/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2011).
- **Are you going to monetize it in some way?**

  I've tried to add a couple of experimental inobstrusive ads links to pay the Google App Engine overquota's bill but never got a click in months, it's not a problem though  since GAE quotas are fairly generous.